# Select table name in Postgresql with inheritance

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, view

So this is my parent table: *TableA*

```
 +-----+-----------+
 + id  +   name    +
 +-----+-----------+
```

And this are the tables that inherit tableA: *TableB* *TableC*

```
+-----+-----------+----------+
+ id  +   date    +   year   +
+-----+-----------+----------+

+-----+-----------+----------+
+ id  +   owner   +   age    +
+-----+-----------+----------+
```

I have a Select where I get an id from the name in TableA, and what I need is to get the name of the table that contains that specific id. I thought about making a view but I'm a noobie and I don't know how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) `tableoid` for that.

The following example:

```
create table table_a (id integer, name text);
create table table_b () inherits (table_a);
create table table_c () inherits (table_a);

insert into table_b values (1, 'one');
insert into table_c values (2, 'two');

select tableoid::regclass as table_name, id, name
from table_a;
```

returns:

```
table_name | id | name
-----------+----+-----
table_b    |  1 | one 
table_c    |  2 | two
```